# $G$ a group of odd order. Then $\forall$ $g\in G$ there is $h\in G$ such that $g=h^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This one is from a practice exam I was working on.

> $G$ a group of odd order. Then for $\forall$ $g\in G$ there is a unique $h\in G$ such that $g=h^2$.

**Thoughts** Well I tried a few things but they didni't come off. For example I tried to show that $g^{-1}$ is in the group and go from there. Also tried the obvious route. Assume such an $h$ doesn't exist and such. But I'm going around in circles. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f: G \to G, f(x)=x^2$.

Prove that $f$ is 1 to 1 (follows immediately from $x^{2k+1}=e=y^{2k+1}$), thus a bijection. Note that $f$ is just a function, not a morphism.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But why is $x$ raised to an odd power the identity?. Do I need to consider the subgroup generated by $x$?. I follow the rest. Because $G$ being finite guarantees its a bijection as long as its injective.

Comment: @user54755  $G$ has an odd order, let $|G|=2k+1$. What is $x^{2k+1}$?

Comment: Oh its because of that corollary to Lagrange's theorem. I get it. Silly me :)

Answer (score 3):

In the usual way, we can show that there is a smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k$ is the identity element $e$. The objects $g,g^2,\dots,g^k$ form a subgroup of $G$.

Thus $k$ divides the order of $G$, so $k$ must be odd.

Note that $g^{k+1}=g$, and $k+1$ is even. Let $h=g^{(k+1)/2}$. Then $h^2=g$.

Comment: And, as $h^2=g$ implies that $h^{-1}=g^k$, you can conclude that $h$ is unique ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking about it too hard. What is the order of the element $g$? Why does this imply the result?

(**Hint:** Consider $\langle g^2\rangle$.)

Comment: (Actually, the line "I think you are thinking about it too hard" is not necessarily true - it is more that you are going in the wrong direction. It is all about the oddness of the order of the group. This question isn't easy until you think about it in the right way.)

Answer (score 1):

Take $h=g^{\frac{|G|+1}{2}}$, then $h^2=g$